# How to organize a Docker Swarm project?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I am trying to organize my Docker Swarm project that is splitted in diffrent git repositories.
Actually there are 4 repositories in total.

Stack repository wraps front, users and products repositories with git submodules.
Each submodule, has its own Dockerfile and a compose manifest to allow setting up each piece individually.

```bash
stack
├── docker-compose.stack.yaml -> prod
├── docker-compose.yaml -> dev
├── products
├── front
├── users
```

For example, Products repo has a PHP app, a Memcached server and a MongoDB server.
Users repo also has a PHP app and a MySQL server.
Front its just a NextJS website that consumes Products and Users from CSR and SSR.

For development purposes, in Stack repo I have a compose manifest that includes every docker-compose.yml of each submodule and also serves a Traefik service to perform routing, reverse proxying and other stuff.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

include:
  - products/docker-compose.yaml
  - front/docker-compose.yaml
  - users/docker-compose.yaml

services:
  traefik:
    ...
```

At this point all works 'fine'.

In production, as Docker Stack does not allow us using 'include' keyword, i am forced to 'copy-paste' every docker-compose.yml of submodules to stack manifest **causing the development environment to no longer be similar to the production environment.**

How can i organize my docker swarm project to make both environments similar?

I have tried copy paste all service manifest to stack manifest to lift all the needs of the different containers.

It must be taken into account that the development databases are only for development, the objective in production is for the containers to connect to a private database, for example in Mongo Atlas or RDS for MySQL. And algo DNS names are not same in production and development.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role==manager
    volumes:
      # FIXME: Insecure volume
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true
      - --entryPoints.web.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:443
      # FIXME: Insecure volume
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - traefik-net

  frontend:
    image: ...
    depends_on:
      - backend-products
      - backend-users
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      labels:
        ...
      replicas: 2

  backend-products:
    image: ...
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    environment:
      ...
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      labels:
        ...
      replicas: 2

  backend-users:
    image: ...
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      labels:
        ...
      replicas: 2

networks:
  traefik-net:
    driver: overlay
```

I would also appreciate any advice related.

Thanks!